# Can I replicate and run someone else's model just using a .pth file?

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to understand exactly what .pth files are and how they can be used to test and run someone else's model.

For example, check out a repository like this: https://github.com/TencentYoutuResearch/PedestrianDetection-NohNMS

Is it possible for me to download the .pth files and create a Keras model from it that will perform / compute the same?

I was thinking instead of downloading and trying to compile the whole repository above, if I just want to test their model, maybe I can just download their .pth file and do something like "my_model = keras.model(pth_file)", you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the https://github.com/gmalivenko/pytorch2keras library does what you want.

In the readme they have also an example to do exactly this.

It's the converter of PyTorch graph to a Keras (Tensorflow backend) model.
Firstly, we need to load (or create) a valid PyTorch model:

```
class TestConv2d(nn.Module):
    """
    Module for Conv2d testing
    """

    def __init__(self, inp=10, out=16, kernel_size=3):
        super(TestConv2d, self).__init__()
        self.conv2d = nn.Conv2d(inp, out, stride=1, kernel_size=kernel_size, bias=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv2d(x)
        return x

model = TestConv2d()

# load weights here
# model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path_to_weights.pth))
```

The next step - create a dummy variable with correct shape:

```
input_np = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1, 10, 32, 32))
input_var = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(input_np))
```

We use the dummy-variable to trace the model (with jit.trace):

```
from pytorch2keras import pytorch_to_keras
# we should specify shape of the input tensor
k_model = pytorch_to_keras(model, input_var, [(10, 32, 32,)], verbose=True)
```

You can also set H and W dimensions to None to make your model shape-agnostic (e.g. fully convolutional netowrk):

```
from pytorch2keras.converter import pytorch_to_keras
# we should specify shape of the input tensor
k_model = pytorch_to_keras(model, input_var, [(10, None, None,)], verbose=True)
```

That's all! If all the modules have converted properly, the Keras model will be stored in the k_model variable.

But this will only work if all the layer are supported, you can find the list in the doc.

Comment: Hey awesome thanks for your response:) Do I need to know and rebuild the full architecture of the pytorch model, or can I use just the .pth file?

Comment: no you first need to build the pth file in a pythorch model, only then you can convert it in a keras model with ```pytorch_to_keras```, this function takes as argument the pythorch model

Comment: yes, unfortunately you still need some knowledge of pytorch to make this work, but you can find plenty of examples here https://github.com/gmalivenko/pytorch2keras/tree/master/tests/models